# ExtJS5 MVVC the CRUD ajax proxy does read but not the other

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, crud

I begin with a little test wich consists on display data from a PostgreSQL in a Grid. The Grid Store has an Ajax Proxy.
Here are the codes:
**model/manage/Client.js**

```
Ext.define('Chronos.model.manage.Client', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields   : [
        {name : 'id',   type: 'int'},
        {name : 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

**store/manage/Client.js**

```
Ext.define('Chronos.store.manage.Clients', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    model    : 'Chronos.model.manage.Client',
    sorters  : ['name'],
    autoLoad : false,
    autosync : true,
    storeId  : 'manageClientsStore',

    proxy : {
        type   : 'ajax', // Ext.data.proxy.Ajax
        api    : {
            create  : 'api/management/clients.create.php',
            read    : 'api/management/clients.read.php',
            update  : 'api/management/clients.update.php',
            destroy : 'api/management/clients.destroy.php'
        },
        reader : {
            type         : 'json', // Ext.data.reader.Json
            rootProperty : 'records'
        },
        writer : {
            type   : 'json', // Ext.data.writer.Json
            encode : true
        }
    }
});
```

**view/manage/Client.js**

```
Ext.define('Chronos.view.manage.Clients', {
    extend   : 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires : [
        'Chronos.view.manage.ClientsController',
        'Chronos.model.manage.Client',
        'Chronos.store.manage.Clients'
    ],

    controller : 'manageclients',
    modal      : true,

    layout : {
        type  : 'vbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    width  : 300,
    height : 500,
    title  : 'Kunden Verwaltung',

    items: [{ // Grid
        xtype    : 'grid',
        store    : 'manage.Clients',
        flex     : 1,
        selType  : 'cellmodel',
        plugins  : 'cellediting',

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                xtype    : 'button',
                icon     : 'resources/icons.32/kunden.neu.png',
                text     : 'Neuer Kunde',
                scale    : 'large',
                handler  : 'onClientAdd'
            }, {
                xtype    : 'button',
                icon     : 'resources/icons.32/kunden.löschen.png',
                text     : 'Kunde löschen',
                scale    : 'large',
                handler  : 'onClientDelete',
                disabled : true
            }]
        }],

        columns: [{
            text: 'id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            align: 'right',
            width: 50,
            hidden: true
        }, {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex : 1,
            editor: {
                xtype     : 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }],
        listeners: {
            render: {
                scope: this,
                fn: function(grid) {
                    grid.getStore().load();
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

The Store is only loading on render, like I want.
It works fine to display data, but not to write them back. Neither Create, Update nor Distroy url are called (I know it, beacause I write a file in the php code).

What have I forgotten?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was OK, but the case of `autoSync`

```
Ext.define('Chronos.store.manage.Clients', {
    ...
    autoSync : true,
```

Sorry